# FTP Server 2008 (This webpage is not available)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ftp, port-forwarding, windows-command-prompt

Im having trouble getting access to my FTP server on a web browser.

On the **local server** i am able to (ftp://192.168.50.11) and login using user name and password using the browser.

On a different machine \ network I am not able to access the ftp site in the browser even if I use the same user name and password but if I open up CMD and ftp into that ip I am able to login and see all the files (DIR)

Is it a port that I need to open or is it something I missed in IIS?

Comment: Are you missing an image link in your post, by any chance?

Comment: Yes Im a new user. Didn't let me post an image

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open port 21 on your Windows Firewall, and perhaps on your network router (perhaps using Port Forwarding?) as long as you have not altered your default FTP port settings.

When you use the FTP command in CMD it will automatically use the right port to access your ftp share.

Comment: Port 21 is open. What we have figured out was in order to see it on IE you have to disable  (Use passive FTP) but still when I try to open it in Chrome or Firefox it still doesn't work.

Comment: The Passive Mode issue you discovered with IE may be the same culprit in Chrome (Extended Passive mode they call it.)

In Firefox, I don't know for certain if FTP is even supported anymore, I know there is an addon called FireFTP that works directly inside Firefox for viewing/connecting to FTP sites.